How do I retrieve the list of active TCP connections in Windows?
I found this function GetEXtendedTcpTable to retrieve all active connections on Windows OS however, only local connections by native processes are returned, how do I retrieve all active connections? Code below:
void Interconnected(){
    printf("debug 1");
    PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID tcpTable;
    DWORD size=0;
    PVOID table;
    DWORD ret;
    ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(NULL, &size, FALSE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0);
    if (ret != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        printf("Unable to determine buffer size. Error code: %lu\n", ret);
        return;
    }

    tcpTable = (PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID)malloc(size);
    if (tcpTable == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for TCP table struct\n");
        return;
    }
    ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, &size, FALSE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0);
    if (ret != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Unable to get TCP table. Error code: %lu\n", ret);
        return;
    }

    if (tcpTable->dwNumEntries == 0) {
        printf("No active TCP connections found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Active TCP connections:\n");
        printf("%-20s %-5s %-20s %-5s %-10s %-10s\n", "Local Address","Port","Remote Address","Port", "PID", "State");

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < tcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
            struct in_addr localAddr, remoteAddr;
            localAddr.S_un.S_addr = tcpTable->table[i].dwLocalAddr;
            remoteAddr.S_un.S_addr = tcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
            unsigned short local_port=ntohs((unsigned short)tcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort);
            unsigned short remote_port=ntohs((unsigned short)tcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort);

            char *state = "Unknown";
            switch (tcpTable->table[i].dwState) {
                    //removed for brevity
            }

            printf("%-20s %-5u %-20s %-5u %-10u %-10s\n",
       inet_ntoa(localAddr),
       local_port,
       inet_ntoa(remoteAddr),
       remote_port,
       tcpTable->table[i].dwOwningPid,
       state);
        }
    }

    free(tcpTable);
}

